# MySQL query returns no results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I know that this type of question has been asked before. 
But it most probably is something to do with the query itself.
right now the whole thing is php tagged. and this is where i think I am going wrong. 
This is a perfectly legit phpmyadmin query and returns desired results:

```
SELECT sm.stockid, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'RT') AS RT, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'TR') AS TR, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'FL') AS FL, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'DE') AS DE FROM stockmaster sm
```

This is the format I have it in:

```
$query = "SELECT sm.stockid, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'RT') AS RT, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'TR') AS TR, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'FL') AS FL, (SELECT price FROM prices WHERE stockid = sm.stockid AND typeabbrev = 'DE') AS DE FROM stockmaster sm";
```

This block of code though prints nothing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);    
$recordCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $recordCount;
```

But in phpmyadmin the query returns the following:

[image: desired results]

I probably need to escape the single quotes or redo my php tagging.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you check this query directly run in your sql?

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` will not return the whole result. It gives only the number of rows. Try once again adding `exit;` after `echo` statement.

Comment: what says var_dump($result); ?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Yes I know, im using that just for testing. the rest of my code wont work unless the query is working. and using the exact same code but with a different query I get number of rows returned. which is why i know its a problem with the query itself.

Comment: @IvoP this is what it shows:
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(37) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(167) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch data using `while` loop.Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);    
$recordCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($recordCount > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      print_r($row);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, im not trying to fetch data yet. I have the data fetching code elsewhere but i have narrowed the problem down to the query not running correctly.

Comment: No errors but i did get this object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(37) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(167) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: You are not getting data because may be possible no match record with `CL`. Try `RT` in place of `CL`

Comment: Yes sorry I have updated the question. I had missed out a line while posting the original question but this is how it is in my code.

Comment: Did you run query in phpmyadmin same as in `$query` variable. I noticed both query are different with `CL` and `RT`?

Comment: Query result showing you have no matching record with given parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I have experienced Problems like this before and solved it by using the object-oriented mysqli methods. Try to make a new mysqli - object and run the query with
    $mysqli->query($sql);
Sometimes this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
Try using $recordCount = $result->num_rows; instead of $recordCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); It should work as mysqli_result object is giving num_rows.

Comment: Hi, no this doesnt work. 
its not an issue with the code. its an issue with the query. If i change the query to say... SELECT * FROM prices
then i will get a value of 60000 printed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd that the query runs OK in `phpmyadmin` but not in your app - might be worth trying a fully quoted and escaped version of the query perhaps.

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';
$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


$sql="SELECT 
    sm.`stockid`, 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'RT' ) AS 'RT', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'TR' ) AS 'TR', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'FL' ) AS 'FL', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'DE' ) AS 'DE' 
    FROM `stockmaster` sm";

$result = $db->query( $sql );
$rows = intval( $result->num_rows );

$result->close();
$db->close();

printf( "Rows: %d", $rows );
```

To test this for myself I built a couple of new tables in a test database and populated with dummy records

```
$a=array('RT','TR','FL','DE');
$r=range( 0.1, 1, 0.01 );

$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'experiments';
$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


$sql='insert into `stockmaster` ( `price`, `typeabbrev` ) values (?,?);';
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$price,$abbrev);
    for( $i=0; $i < 100 ; $i++ ){
        shuffle( $r );
        shuffle( $a );
        $abbrev = $a[ array_rand( $a ) ];
        $price = $r[ array_rand( $r ) ];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

A quick mysql cmd query

```
mysql> select * from stockmaster
+---------+-------+------------+
| stockid | price | typeabbrev |
+---------+-------+------------+
|       1 |  0.35 | TR         |
|       2 |  0.70 | FL         |
|       3 |  0.91 | FL         |
|       4 |  0.97 | DE         | 
...... etc ~ there are 100 rows 
|      99 |  0.78 | RT         |
|     100 |  0.81 | FL         |
+---------+-------+------------+
100 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select * from prices;
+-----+-------+------------+
| pid | price | typeabbrev |
+-----+-------+------------+
|  18 |  0.96 | TR         |
|  78 |  0.77 | FL         |
|  81 |  0.36 | RT         |
|  99 |  0.69 | DE         |
+-----+-------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


$sql="SELECT 
    sm.`stockid`, 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'RT' ) AS 'RT', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'TR' ) AS 'TR', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'FL' ) AS 'FL', 
    ( SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `stockid` = sm.`stockid` AND `typeabbrev` = 'DE' ) AS 'DE' 
    FROM `stockmaster` sm";

$result = $db->query( $sql );
$rows = intval( $result->num_rows );

$result->close();
$db->close();

printf( "Rows: %d", $rows );
```

And this then outputs

```
Rows: 100
```

I realise the data in these test tables is not the same but I would be confident that with the actual data it would work in PHP...Weird!

Comment: Hi, This also doesn't work unfortunately. doesn't print anything so that means its not getting any rows from the query.
I think the problem arises when using AS and brackets.

Comment: Yes very weird. Thats where im stuck. works in phpmyadmin but not in the app although nothing wrong with the rest of the code since it will return number of rows for a simpler query.

Answer (score -1):

In phpmyadmin running your query is giving you the result hence the table like output. 
But *in php what you are doing is simply getting the number of rows in your result and echoing it*.

If you want to print the table like output using php you need do to something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);   
$recordCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row;
}
```

NOTE:
You can skip the mysqli_num_rows if you don't want to use the number of rows of your result in your code.

**Also I noticed that your query in phpmyadmin and php code is not exactly same. Did you try it with the exact same queries? Because the echo $recordCount should have atleast given you the number of rows.**

Comment: Hi, the issue is not with showing the table. that code is in a different part of the application and is working fine with other queries. but i expected the code i posted here to show 6000 as number of rows but it doesnt. it doesnt show anything but also shows no errors.
Its exactly the same omitting the enclosing double quotes and the semi colon at the end.

Comment: _But the values of typeabrev are different in the two queries_ What I meant was did you try the same phpmyadmin query i.e with the same values of typeabrev?

Comment: Yes sorry you are correct. I have updated the question. but no it does not work with that exact query.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand where the problem is occurring. everything looks fine to me now

Comment: this is also where im stuck, haha. :)
but i have narrowed it down to the php application not reading the query correctly. this is why i was thinking that it may be because of the brackets or quotes or something?

Comment: try one thing. Try out a very simple query without the where clause and see if you get any output or not. Quotes and single quotes are fine , but I am not sure about the brackets tho. And did you try it out with the brackets removed?

Comment: Yes a simple query works and returns number of rows. i tested with SELECT * FROM prices;
with the brackets removed the query also doesnt work :(